# Post MultipartFile - Request Part not preset Error

Tags: spring, post, multipartform-data, ionic4, multipart

#### I try to send an **image** from a **ionic** Front-End application through a **post** method to Back-End services in **Spring boot**

I have done this method that makes the post to the backend url with the image inside a FormData object:

```
  uploadImageService(url: string, image: any) {
     console.log('post service: upload Image', + url);
     // Initiates a FormData object to be sent to the server
     const fd: FormData = new FormData();
     fd.append('file', image);
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
     console.log('form data file: \n' + fd.get('file'));
     xhr.open('POST', url);
     // Send the FormData
     xhr.send(fd);
     console.log(xhr.response);
     return xhr.responseText;
  }

// call this method:

this.webapiService.uploadImageService(this.globalDataService.getUrlMedium() 'riskcontrol/subir-imagen', this.selectedImage);
```

This is the spring boot method that collects this post:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/subir-imagen")
    public ResponseEntity handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
       LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "/Post, handleFileUpload", file);     
       String associatedFileURL = fileManagerService.storageFile(file);
       return ResponseEntity.ok(associatedFileURL);
  }
```

When I do the post of the image I get this **error**:

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]

I have launched the petition through **Postman** and it has worked, 
that's why I think the error is in the tyscript code.

The only difference I see between postman and the code, is that in the form-data, let mark the **key** as *type file* or *type text*, and I have chosen type file.

I tried to make the request post in another way:

```
const httpOptionsImages = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE'
  })
};


// function

uploadImageService(url: string, image: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log('post service: upload Image', + url);
    // Initiates a FormData object to be sent to the server
    const fd: FormData = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', image);

    return this.http
        .post(url, fd, httpOptionsImages);
  }


// call to the function

this.webapiService.uploadImageService(this.globalDataService.getUrlMedium() + 'riskcontrol/subir-imagen', this.selectedImage)
        .subscribe( result => {
          console.log(result);
});
```

But in this way I got another **error**:

> FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any way to indicate to **FormData** that the key is of type *file* as in postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the image as a `Blob` follow [Ionic tutorial](https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/02/Uploading-pictures-from-Ionic-2-to-Spring-Boot.html)

> ```
>  const imgBlob = new Blob([reader.result], {type: file.type});
>   formData.append('file', imgBlob, file.name);
> ```
>
> In the readFile function the program utilizes the FileReader from the File API to read the file into an ArrayBuffer. The onloadend event is called as soon as the file is successfully read. The app then creates a FormData object, wraps the array buffer in a Blob and adds it to the FormData object with the name 'file'. This is the same name the server expects as request parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by reader? 
I've put the code in the following way: and it seems to work well   `uploadImageService(url: string, param: any) {
    const fd: FormData = new FormData();
    const imgBlob = new Blob([param.result], {type: param.type});
    fd.append('file', imgBlob, param.name);`

Comment: @MaríaCristinaFernándezLópez It's just a quote from link, the key is to create the `Blob`

Comment: I have come across another problem, now the image arrives at the server but empty, which must be passed as parameters to the blob? I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on using `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam` for `MultipartFile file`.